# How do I enable MultipleActiveResultSets in application running on appharbor with sequelizer add-on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, appharbor

While developing locally, I have a connection string set with MultipleActiveResultSets set equal to TRUE. However, when I deploy my app and the sequelizer connectionString gets injected, MultipleActiveResultSets is left out. Is there anyway to enable MultipleActiveResultSets or otherwise update the connection string?

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 by the way.

Comment: I think if you use your own connection string rather than the injected SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING it should be fine?

Only issue is that if appharbor decides to move your DB it will break your app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update: Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) can now be enabled for the injected connection string by using the Sequelizer admin panel. This is the recommended approach since the `web.config` no longer needs to be modified, which causes an `AppDomain` reload during startup*

You can construct the connectionstring from the URI injected into your application `web.config`. The process is described [here](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1874-how-to-enable-multiple-active-result-sets-when-using-ef-41-and-sequelizer-add-on), but I'm including the snippet below too:

```
var uriString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLSERVER_URI"];
var uri = new Uri(uriString);
var connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = uri.Host,
    InitialCatalog = uri.AbsolutePath.Trim('/'),
    UserID = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').First(),
    Password = uri.UserInfo.Split(':').Last(),
    MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
}.ConnectionString;
```

Note the `MultipleActiveResultSets = true`.

If you need to also build a non-Code-First connectionstring, you then need to use a `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` for the rest, eg.:

```
var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;
builder.Metadata = "somemetadata";
builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
```

(also [answered on the AppHarbor support forum](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1874-how-to-enable-multiple-active-result-sets-when-using-ef-41-and-sequelizer-add-on))

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where/when would the proper place be to create the connection string? Is one time, on app start enough? Or does the sequalizer connection string change dynamically throughout the lifetime of my app and need to be updated? I guess this part is where I am lost.

Comment: It seems as if whether or not I have this code run on app start a connection string is still getting injected into my web config(the one without MARS enabled either way).

Comment: You can modify your EF context constructor to use the modified connectionstring, as is done here: https://github.com/friism/folketsting/blob/master/FT.Data/DB.Designer.cs#L81

Comment: Is it possible that the connection string for sequelizer could change at some point(if app harbor decides to move my db) and my app could break? Considering that I am only dynamically creating my correct string once on application_start...or would my app be redeployed if the database was moved/changed by appharbor?

Comment: Please see the [AppHarbor support post for full answer](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1874-how-to-enable-multiple-active-result-sets-when-using-ef-41-and-sequelizer-add-on).

Comment: Do keep in mind that if the Web.config changes (such as a changed connection string) then the app will be restarted.